# error: cannot find symbol public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<EmsApplication>

Tags: android, dagger

Hello I am newbie in dagger. I am trying to learn but I am facing a issue in generating AppComponent class. Here is my `AppComponent` class code. I searched some answer in stackoverflow but none of them not working.

```
import EmsApplication
import android.app.Application
import com.example.emsapplication.utils.SessionManager
import dagger.BindsInstance
import dagger.Component
import dagger.android.AndroidInjector
import dagger.android.support.AndroidSupportInjectionModule
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Component(modules = \[AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, ActivityBuildersModule::class, AppModule::class, ViewModelFactoryModule::class\])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<EmsApplication>{
    fun sessionManager(): SessionManager?

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application?): Builder?

        fun build(): AppComponent?
    }
}
```

```
error: cannot find symbol public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<EmsApplication>
```

Here is the output of build event.

[image: Here is the build output]

[image: Here is the build.gradle]

[image: EmsApplication]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A silly mistake take my 6 hours to find out hope this answer will help you out.

- In my case i didn't give my package in my application class.
- Please make sure that You also give your package name in every classes.[image]

Comment: Ho man, I didn't have the package in my test file and I got this error, thanks!.

Comment: Thanks, this is amazing, i would have spent more on this issue without this....the error is so stupid 

Comment: wow this worked , thank you

Answer (score 1):

try changing your code into.

```
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<EmsApplication> {
 fun sessionManager(): SessionManager?
 @Component.Builder
 interface Builder {
      @BindInstance
      fun application(application: EmsApplication): Builder
      fun build():AppComponent
```

}

Can you provide more about this ? your EmsApplication. it will help too.

Comment: check .. i added a image of EmsApplication.

Comment: have you add your EmsApplication in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yes . I added it on application level as name

Comment: I am following a tutorial series that was in java and i am doing same thing in kotlin and facing this problem.

Comment: `class EmsApplication : Application(), HasAndroidInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var activityDispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = activityDispatchingAndroidInjector

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
            .inject(this)
    }
}` change your EmsApplication to this and try again.

Comment: you might face HasAndroidInjector not found, you have to update your dagger 2 version to latest because in new version, it remove the boilerplate codes such as "HasActivityInjector,... " and use common for all "HasAndroidInjector".

Comment: Cool bro. you are welcome. Actually you might need to change `@BindInstance
      fun application(application: EmsApplication): Builder` to `@BindInstance
      fun application(application: Application): Builder`.